# SIGPROF on darwin

Tags: profiler, darwin

setitimer + sigprof doesn't work on 64 bit darwin.

References:

http://openradar.appspot.com/9336975

http://lists.apple.com/archives/Unix-porting/2007/Aug/msg00000.html

Given this, what's the recommended way to build a time based, sampling profiler on darwin? In a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate profiler thread that sleeps for intervals and `pthread_kills` all other threads with `SIGPROF`. The `SIGPROF` handler looks at the how much cpu time the thread consumed and punts if it's too little.